# Fetching Google Analytics Data using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can i fetch google analytics data using Vuejs. I search and tried but still can't figure it out how to fetch data.

**EDIT**

I tried this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#make_an_api_call

but i got error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a nodejs library and it won't work in the browser